# (JUNIT/Spring 3.2) No thread-bound request found: Are you referring to request attributes outside of an actual web request

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, spring-mvc, junit

I am trying to run a simple test case in spring base junit test class. In that script, one of the methods in that script is using request attribute as below:

```
ServletRequestAttributes attr = (ServletRequestAttributes) RequestContextHolder.currentRequestAttributes();
return (User) attr.getRequest().getSession().getAttribute("user");
```

So I need to set request attribute at before running the test script.

Test script is

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = { "/SpringConfig-servlet.xml"})
@WebAppConfiguration
public class DocumentTest {

//@Autowired
//protected SessionFactory sessionFactory;

@Autowired
protected SetUpScript setUpScript;

 @Autowired MockHttpSession session;

@Autowired MockHttpServletRequest request;


@Before
public void setup() {
    //Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
   // TransactionSynchronizationManager.bindResource(sessionFactory,new SessionHolder(session));
    //MockHttpServletRequest request = new MockHttpServletRequest();
    //MockHttpSession session = new MockHttpSession();
    request.setSession(session);
    RequestContextHolder.setRequestAttributes(new ServletRequestAttributes(request));
}

@Test
public void test() {
    setUpScript.saveDocument();
}



}
```

But it is not working as per expected, I am getting below error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
    at org.springframework.test.context.CacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(CacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:99)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContext.getApplicationContext(TestContext.java:122)
    at org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.setUpRequestContextIfNecessary(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:105)
    at org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:74)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:312)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:211)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:284)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:231)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:88)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:174)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.execute(JUnit4Provider.java:252)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:141)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:112)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethodWithArray(ReflectionUtils.java:189)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory$ProviderProxy.invoke(ProviderFactory.java:165)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory.invokeProvider(ProviderFactory.java:85)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:115)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:75)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mailConnector': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.devdarshan.dao.GenericDaoImpl org.devdarshan.utility.MailConnector.mailApiDao; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'genericDaoImpl': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.hibernate.SessionFactory org.devdarshan.dao.GenericDaoImpl.sessionFactory; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in class path resource [SpringConfig-servlet.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not get constructor for org.hibernate.
ersister.entity.SingleTableEntityPersister
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:288)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1116)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:458)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:295)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:292)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:628)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:932)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:479)
    at org.springframework.test.context.web.AbstractGenericWebContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericWebContextLoader.java:128)
    at org.springframework.test.context.web.AbstractGenericWebContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericWebContextLoader.java:60)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.delegateLoading(AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.java:100)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.java:248)
    at org.springframework.test.context.CacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(CacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:64)
    at org.springframework.test.context.CacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(CacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:91)
    ... 31 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.devdarshan.dao.GenericDaoImpl org.devdarshan.utility.MailConnector.mailApiDao; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'genericDaoImpl': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.hibernate.SessionFactory org.devdarshan.dao.GenericDaoImpl.sessionFactory; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in class path resource [SpringConfig-servlet.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not get constructor for org.hibernate.persister.entity.SingleTableEntityPersister
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:514)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:87)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:285)
    ... 47 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'genericDaoImpl': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.hibernate.SessionFactory org.devdarshan.dao.GenericDaoImpl.sessionFactory; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in class path resource [SpringConfig-servlet.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not get constructor for org.hibernate.persister.entity.SingleTableEntityPersister
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:288)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1116)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:458)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:295)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:292)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:912)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:855)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:770)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:486)
    ... 49 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.hibernate.SessionFactory org.devdarshan.dao.GenericDaoImpl.sessionFactory; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in class path resource [SpringConfig-servlet.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not get constructor for org.hibernate.persister.entity.SingleTableEntityPersister
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:514)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:87)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:285)
    ... 60 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in class path resource [SpringConfig-servlet.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not get constructor for org.hibernate.persister.entity.SingleTableEntityPersister
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1482)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:521)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:458)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:295)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:292)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:912)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:855)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:770)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:486)
    ... 62 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not get constructor for org.hibernate.persister.entity.SingleTableEntityPersister
    at org.hibernate.persister.internal.PersisterFactoryImpl.create(PersisterFactoryImpl.java:185)
    at org.hibernate.persister.internal.PersisterFactoryImpl.createEntityPersister(PersisterFactoryImpl.java:135)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:386)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1794)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1865)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBuilder.buildSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBuilder.java:247)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean.buildSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:373)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:358)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1541)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1479)
    ... 72 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.InstantiationException: could not instantiate test objectorg.devdarshan.beans.Document
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.UnsavedValueFactory.instantiate(UnsavedValueFactory.java:49)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.UnsavedValueFactory.getUnsavedIdentifierValue(UnsavedValueFactory.java:68)
    at org.hibernate.tuple.PropertyFactory.buildIdentifierProperty(PropertyFactory.java:75)
    at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.EntityMetamodel.<init>(EntityMetamodel.java:145)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.<init>(AbstractEntityPersister.java:507)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.SingleTableEntityPersister.<init>(SingleTableEntityPersister.java:146)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)
    at org.hibernate.persister.internal.PersisterFactoryImpl.create(PersisterFactoryImpl.java:163)
    ... 81 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.UnsavedValueFactory.instantiate(UnsavedValueFactory.java:46)
    ... 91 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No thread-bound request found: Are you referring to request attributes outside of an actual web request, or processing a request outside of the originally receiving thread? If you are actually operating within a web request and still receive this message, your code is probably running outside of DispatcherServlet/DispatcherPortlet: In this case, use RequestContextListener or RequestContextFilter to expose the current request.
    at org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextHolder.currentRequestAttributes(RequestContextHolder.java:131)
    at org.devdarshan.utility.UtilityServices.getUser(UtilityServices.java:27)
    at org.devdarshan.beans.Auditable.<init>(Auditable.java:21)
    at org.devdarshan.beans.Document.<init>(Document.java:13)
    ... 96 more
```

I found the following main resources

1. http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/testing.html
2. [Unit testing a method dependent to the request context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9419606/unit-testing-a-method-dependent-to-the-request-context)

I have also added request context listner in my web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app 
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    version="2.5">

    <display-name>Sample</display-name>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

    <!-- Config here. -->
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>SpringConfig</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
          <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
          <param-value>classpath:SpringConfig-servlet.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>SpringConfig</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.htm</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>

<!-- <context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>classpath:SpringConfig-servlet.xml</param-value>
  </context-param>-->

  <listener>

    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener</listener-class>

  </listener> 

  <error-page>
    <error-code>404</error-code>
    <location>/404error.jsp</location>
   </error-page>

   <jsp-config>
  <jsp-property-group>
    <display-name>SpringConfig</display-name>
    <url-pattern>/WEB-INF/pages/*</url-pattern>
    <el-ignored>false</el-ignored>
    <scripting-invalid>false</scripting-invalid>
    <is-xml>false</is-xml>
    <include-prelude>/WEB-INF/pages/Minheader.jspf</include-prelude>
    <include-coda>/WEB-INF/pages/Minfooter.jspf</include-coda>
  </jsp-property-group>

  <taglib>
    <taglib-uri>customDateLib</taglib-uri>
    <taglib-location>/META-INF/CustomDate.tld</taglib-location>
  </taglib>

</jsp-config>

</web-app>
```

There are many solutions availble on google, but none of them are working for me. I don't know whats going wrong I have almost spent more than full day to resolve this but not able to figure out, what's going wrong here.

Finally I am using following version

1. Spring - 3.2.4.RELEASE
2. Junit - 4.12

Any help will be appreceated.

Comment: Why are you creating instances of a `User` during startup of your application? (Or is it even worse in a `static` block). Next to that I would say it is a bad idea to depend for that logic on the request attributes, because you have now tied your whole application to the web layer.

Comment: It's in constructor when Document is created. I am getting user object for getting audit by whom Document is created or update. I also feel that's a bad idea, can you please suggest whatever could be alternative whenever I particulary want to audit which user have made updation.

Comment: Then again, why are you creating an instance when you are starting the application... It happens during applications startup, why?

Comment: No, it doesn't happen when the application starts up, it happens when I am creating a document object in junit test case.

Comment: according to your logging it is during startup. There is nothing for the execution of the method in there. It already fails when starting. Unless, the horror, you are again creating application context instances yourself, which would make things even worse...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

During initialization of your application context Hibernate instantiate a Document object during the initialization of it's PersistanceFactory and it leads to the following error :

```
org.hibernate.InstantiationException: could not instantiate test objectorg.devdarshan.beans.Document
```

The reason why you cannot instantiate it is just bellow :

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No thread-bound request found: Are you referring to request attributes outside of an actual web request, or processing a request outside of the originally receiving thread? If you are actually operating within a web request and still receive this message, your code is probably running outside of DispatcherServlet/DispatcherPortlet: In this case, use RequestContextListener or RequestContextFilter to expose the current request.
at org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextHolder.currentRequestAttributes(RequestContextHolder.java:131)
at org.devdarshan.utility.UtilityServices.getUser(UtilityServices.java:27)
at org.devdarshan.beans.Auditable.<init>(Auditable.java:21)
at org.devdarshan.beans.Document.<init>(Document.java:13)
... 96 more
```

On the constructor of the Document Object you use the UtilityServices.getUser() method that utilizes the RequestContextHolder.currentRequestAttributes().
It is bad practice to initialize an object based on request parameters. If you need to do this, the scope of the been needs to be "request" and you need to initialize it from a controller or a filter linked to Spring ...

I strongly suggest to change the way you bootstrap your application to not rely on the servlet container and be able to test it easily. The fact that Hibernate instanciate an object at startup can be questionable but as we cannot change it you need to workaround it by not depending on the request in the constuctor of the Document. It's a limitation in the JPA implementation of Hibernate.

Comment: I will also face the same issue with your suggestion. Give me the answer relavant to question. Why I am getting error even I have initialize request attribute?

Comment: I explain why you have the exception, you use the request during the initialization of spring context (during the initialization of a spring bean, in it's constructor). That's your issue. 
When you initialize a mock request in your test, it's too late, the spring context is already initialized due to the @ContextConfiguration annotation.
To solve the issue, you need to modify the constuctor of your Document to not use the request anymore.

Comment: I am getting the same answer even after I removed @WebAppConfiguration, I am not able to understand why it is initiating Document object while server startup?

Comment: Apparently, Hibernate create a Document object (a test object) during the initialization of the PersistanceFactory, you can see that in the org.hibernate.InstantiationException: could not instantiate test objectorg.devdarshan.beans.Document exception. As the constructor of Document depends upon the request, it's the root cause of the issue. I'll update my answer to add this information

Comment: Ok, that makes sense. Thanks.